# Python, webdriver and two Chrome instances

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have my first test in Python and selenium webdriver.
My first file is with class login (login.py):

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


class Login:
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def login(mylogin):
        user_name_input = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
        user_name_input.send_keys(mylogin.email)
        password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
        password_input.send_keys(mylogin.password)
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
```

Next I created first_test.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from login import Login


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("http://test2.test.com/")
driver.maximize_window()


l = Login("test@test.com", "Password1")
l.login()

driver.close()
```

And after run I have to instances (two times run) Chrome. On console I have:

```
Looking for [chromedriver 78.0.3904.105 win32] driver in cache 
File found in cache by path [C:\Users\Boli\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\78.0.3904.105\win32\chromedriver.exe]

Looking for [chromedriver 78.0.3904.105 win32] driver in cache 
File found in cache by path [C:\Users\Boli\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\78.0.3904.105\win32\chromedriver.exe]
```

How to change my code to start only one time Chrome (webrowser)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is you have this line of code:

> driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

in BOTH the login.py module AND the first_test.py.  Since the latter imports the former, there are two instances of webdriver.Chrome() being created.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
But if I delete Chrome driver from login.py - remove line:

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

I have error:

Looking for [chromedriver 78.0.3904.105 win32] driver in cache 
File found in cache by path [C:\Users\Boli\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\78.0.3904.105\win32\chromedriver.exe]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Test/first_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    l.login()
  File "D:\Test\login.py", line 13, in login
    user_name_input = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

Comment: That's because you should pass the driver to your function as a formal parameter instead of using a module level global. That way both can use the same instance.

Comment: I admit that I do not fully understand - I'm at the beginning of writing tests...

Comment: OK, I pass driver as a parameter:
def __init__(self, email, password, **driver**):